# Create POST request in Littlest JupyterHub

Tags: javascript, python, http-post, jupyterhub

I am working on [Littlest JupyterHub (LTJH)](https://tljh.jupyter.org/en/latest/), a multi-user environment without a server and database.

I am trying to create a POST request without any backend server (Flask, PHP, Asp.net, Node.js etc.). To do this, I have created `send POST request` in JavaScript code in a `custom-preloaded.js` file that exists in `/opt/tljh/user/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nbclassic/static/custom` of LTJH. This will be automatically loaded into the notebook. The JavaScript code is as follows:

```
// Create a new XMLHttpRequest object
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

// Prepare the request
var url = '/hub/api'; // API endpoint
var data = {
          message: 'Hello, world!' // Replace with the message you want to send
};
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);

// Set up the request
xhr.open('POST', url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');

// Define a callback function to handle the response
xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 400) {
            // Success!
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
    } else {
            // Error
            console.error('Request failed with status code ' + xhr.status);
    }
};

// Send the request
xhr.send(jsonData);
```

Next, I want to receive the `message` data using python script `loggin.py` that will be placed in the `opt/tljh/config/jupyterhub_config.d` path. The code will receive the data from JavaScript and write it in a log file using `logging` package of Python. The python is as follows:

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs

def server_start_hook(spawner):
    username = spawner.user.name
    logging.info(f"Server started for user: {username}")

    # Store the initial URL when the server starts
    user_url = spawner.server.url
    logging.info(f"Initial URL for user {username}: {user_url}")

def server_stop_hook(spawner):
    username = spawner.user.name
    logging.info(f"Server stopped for user: {username}")

# Configure logging and hooks
log_file = 'logfile.log'
log_format = '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
log_formatter = logging.Formatter(log_format)

file_handler = RotatingFileHandler(log_file, maxBytes=1048576, backupCount=3)
file_handler.setFormatter(log_formatter)

logging.root.addHandler(file_handler)
logging.root.setLevel(logging.INFO)

logging.getLogger('jupyterhub').setLevel(logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('tornado').setLevel(logging.WARNING)

c.Spawner.pre_spawn_hook = server_start_hook
c.Spawner.post_stop_hook = server_stop_hook

# Get the message from the query parameters
query_params = parse_qs(urlparse(os.environ['REQUEST_URI']).query)
message = query_params.get('message', [''])[0]

# Log the message
logging.info(f"Received message: {message}")
```

In the Python code mentioned above, the function `server_start_hook` and `server_stop_hook` are to write a log when the user activates or turns off the server.

The JavaScript code prints in console the error `Method not allowed`. And the Python code is also not working, it stops the entire LTJH server and turns it into a bad gateway. Please help!